# Unable mock static method using mockito

Tags: java, rest, methods, static, mockito

```
try (MockedStatic<EndorsementWS> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(EndorsementWS.class)) {
    utilities.when(() -> EndorsementWS.invokeEndorsementWS(any(),any(),any()))
            .thenReturn(new HashMap<String,String>());
}
```

Not able to mock ENdorsementWS class which is having invokeEndorsementWS with three parameters can someone check this?

Tried with above code but the flow going through the real method not provided stubbed behaviour

Comment: Where is the call to method under test?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```java
try (MockedStatic<EndorsementWS> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(Mockito.mock(EndorsementWS.class))) {
    utilities.when(() -> EndorsementWS.invokeEndorsementWS(any(),any(),any()))
            .thenReturn(new HashMap<String,String>());
}
```

you should use `Mockito.mock()` to mock EndorsementWS class first